TYPO3 v.9.5 - tt_news, replace the URL of a news detail page with the article title
I can't find a decision on how to replace the URL of a news detail page with the article title.
My project: TYPO3 v.9.5, with the tt_news extension. In the documentation the Enhancer with the extension "News system" (tx_news) is used. In my case – the “News” extension (tt_news), where there are no controllers with actions like in tx_news (_controller: 'News::detail').
RealUrl is no longer supported in this version of TYPO3.
Appreciate for the answers.
